# React Data sending issue

Tags: reactjs, axios, token, forgot-password, react-tsx

The scenario is forgotpassword.I have done everything from my backend. The only problem is React.I have manage to read header token.And I would like to send token and new password to my back-end with api. As you see down below I can send password easly. But I dont know how send token from URLSearchParams. Is there any usefull idea for that?

```
const initialValues = {
  password: '',
  changepassword: '',
}
```

```
export function PasswordConfirm() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [hasErrors, setHasErrors] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined)
  const {search} = useLocation()
useEffect(() => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search)
  const token = query.get('token')
  console.log(token) 
},)

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: PasswordConfirmSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, {setStatus, setSubmitting}) => {
      setLoading(true)
      setHasErrors(undefined)
      setTimeout(() => {
        requestPasswordConfirm(values.changepassword,values.password)
          .then(({data: {result}}) => {
            setHasErrors(false)
            setLoading(false)
          })
          .catch(() => {
            setHasErrors(true)
            setLoading(false)
            setSubmitting(false)
            setStatus('The login detail is incorrect')
          })
      }, 1000)
    },
  })
```

```
export function requestPasswordConfirm(token:string,password:string) {
  return axios.post<{result: boolean}>(REQUEST_PASSWORD_URL, {
    token,
    password
  })
}
```

Comment: you can store token in localStorage while logging for the first time and then you can easily fetch the token from the localstorage and send it in your api

Comment: I assume cookie will be better for back end service but i dont know how :) is there any example for that?